# Iterating over values in character vector with dplyr functions

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, tibble

I have several variables (`id.type` and `id.subtype` in this example) I would like to check for distinct values in a tibble `all.snags` using the `dplyr` package. I would like them sorted and all values printed out in the console (a tibble typically prints only the first 10). The output would be equivalent to the following code:

```
distinct(all.snags,id.type)  %>% arrange(id.type) %>% print(n = Inf)
distinct(all.snags,id.subtype) %>% arrange(id.subtype) %>% print(n = Inf)
```

I think this is better done by looping over the values in a vector, but I can't get it to work.

```
distinct.vars  <- c("id.type","id.subtype")
for (i in distinct.vars) {
    distinct(all.snags,distinct.vars[i]) %>% 
    arrange(distinct.vars[i]) %>% 
    print(n = Inf)
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. The first two lines of code you wrote seem to do what you want, so what is the issue?

Comment: It's more scaleable if the code is only written once and additional variables can be added to the existing character vector.

Comment: Sounds like you want a function then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this function is what you want:

```
library(dplyr)

df = iris

print_distinct = function(df, columns) {
  for (c in columns) {
    print(df %>% distinct_(c) %>% arrange_(c))
  }
}

print_distinct(df, c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width"))
```

Comment: That works, except I want to look at each column individually, not together.